# Javascript in anchor tag not working in FireFox and IE. Does work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to debug a browser issue.  The user can click the Change Password button which brings up a colorbox modal popup.  If they click "Yes" nothing happens in Firefox or IE, but it works in Chrome.

```
                <a href="#doneChangePassword" id="changePasswordActivate" class="right modal button">Change Password</a>
                **<input class="hidden" type="submit" id="changePasswordButton" value="Change Password" />**

</section>

<div id="changePasswordContainer" class="modal_container confirm">
    <div id="doneChangePassword">
        <div>
            <div style="padding:10px;">
                <p style="font:size: 18px; text-align: center;">You are changing the password for<br /><strong>@TempData["UserFullName"]</strong>.</p>
                <div style="width: 180px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
                    <p style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;">Are you sure?</p>
                    <div class="closeBox right button_disabled_plain" onclick="$.colorbox.close();">No</div>
                    **<a href="javascript:$.colorbox.close();document.getElementById('changePasswordButton').click();return false;" class="left button">Yes</a>**
                    <div class="clr"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't use inline javascript

Comment: Can you post the full code

Comment: Agree, not the best use.

Comment: Chrome is faster, so it manages to load the plugin before the anchor is loaded, while the other browsers don't. This happens because this is a bad, bad way to do things, and you should be using a proper event handler instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and bind a [click event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to the element

If you must do inline Javascript, It is also usually more reliable at least to use the HTML [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) attribute. If you do this I suggest you don't use the 'a' tag so you don't have to deal with the default behavior of it being a link. Use a span or div and style it how you like.

```
    <span onclick="myfunction()" class="left button">Yes</span>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     // as pointed out by the comment, the colorbox library may not have loaded yet..
     // if using jquery you could wrap this function in the page load event 
       function myfunction() {
            $.colorbox.close();
            document.getElementById('changePasswordButton').click();
        }
    </script>
```